# How to add Custom alerts to modal.js file in magento2

Tags: magento2, alert

I wants to add custom alert for `modal.js` file in `magento 2`.

When **click on** product item **delete button**.

Thanks.

Comment: So to be clear: when you are going to delete a product in the admin grid you want to show a custom alert modal? If so, please clarify this more in your question. It's very generic now.

Comment: Thanks for reply, its not in admin it is in front end

Comment: delete the product after add to cart

Comment: Fro delete button i wants to add

Comment: add your all code